# How do I use Flask routes with Apache and mod_wsgi?

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, flask

I've got my Apache server setup and it is handling Flask responses via mod_wsgi.  I've registered the WSGI script via the alias:

[httpd.conf]

```
WSGIScriptAlias /service "/mnt/www/wsgi-scripts/service.wsgi"
```

I've added the corresponding WSGI file at the above path:

[/mnt/www/wsgi-scripts/service.wsgi]

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/mnt/www/wsgi-scripts")

from service import application
```

And I have a simple test Flask Python script that provides the service module:

[/mnt/www/wsgi-scripts/service.py]

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def application(environ, start_response):
        status = '200 OK'
        output = "Hello World!"
        response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                            ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
        start_response(status, response_headers)
        return [output]

@app.route('/upload')
def upload(environ, start_response):
        output = "Uploading"
        status = '200 OK'
        response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                            ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
        start_response(status, response_headers)
        return [output]

if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run()
```

When I go to my website URL [hostname]/service it works as expected and I get "Hello World!" back.  The problem is that I don't know how to get other routes to work like, like 'upload' in the example above.  This works fine in standalone Flask but under mod_wsgi I'm stumped.  The only thing I can imagine is registering a separate WSGI script alias in the httpd.conf for each endpoint I want, but that takes away Flask's fancy routing support.  Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Have you tried browsing to `/service/upload`? You might be pleasantly surprised.

Comment: When I hit /service/upload the request still gets sent to the 'application' function.  In fact, I can remove the route statement before the application function and it still works.  It's like the application is always being used by mod_wsgi as the entry point to the application.  It feels like I need to do something inside 'application' that kicks off Flask's routing logic.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your wsgi file you are doing `from service import application`, which is importing only your `application` method.

Change that to `from service import app as application` and everything will work as expected.

After your comment, I thought I'd expand the answer a bit:

Your wsgi file is python code - you can have any valid python code inside this file. The wsgi "handler" that is installed in Apache is looking for the *application* name in this file, which it will hand off requests to. A Flask class instance - `app = Flask(__name__)` - provides such an interface, but since its called `app` and not `application`, you have to alias it when you import it - that's what the from line does.

You could - and this is perfectly fine - simply do this `application = Flask(__name__)` and then point the wsgi handler in Apache to your `service.py` file. If `service.py` was importable (that means, somewhere in `PYTHONPATH`), you wouldn't need an intermediary wsgi script.

Although the above works, its bad practice. The wsgi file needs permissions from the Apache process to work; and you generally separate that from the actual source code which should be somewhere else on your filesystem, with appropriate permissions.

Comment: that did the trick.  Thank you!  In addition to changing service.wsgi to match what you indicated, I also needed to revert my service.py to be pure flask.  In the original problem statement I think I'd gotten off the rails mixing pure mod_wsgi code with Flask.  I think the genesis of this confusion was naming my root route handler 'application'.

Comment: I think I was unclear about mod_wsgi vs. Flask code. I understand that it's all Python.  What I was getting stuck on is that in the example above my `@app.route('/')` is decorating the function `application`.  In my original setup I was importing just application so only that function was getting called.  When I changed the _service.wsgi_ to use `from service import app as application` that did correctly reference the Flask object, but it also seems to have created a naming conflict with the `application` function.  I renamed this function to `@def root():` and now it works fine. Thanks again!

Comment: Sweet! This was the answer to my woes.